# Generation of dynamic class from XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml, vb.net, json.net

What I am trying to achieve is convert XML to a JSON object. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    ' other properties here'
End Class

Dim doc As XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(arg_strXml)
Dim jsonValue As String = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)
Dim jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Person)(jsonValue)

Dim firstName As String = jsonObject.Name
```

However the issue is the retrieved XML, and thus the deserialized JSON object has different fields/properties/elements depending on the correct function. It would be a nightmare to have a class for each possible XML.

Is there a way round not having to create a specific class (Person in this case) for each deserialize?

Comment: Yes.  Parse it rather than deserialize it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to convert it to JSON instead of just using the XML?  LINQ to XML is pretty nice in VB.NET.

Comment: Mainly for performance, before we were using GetPropertyValue(Of String)("NodeName"). How would Linq to XML help?

Comment: Try this `Dim doc  As XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(arg_strXml)
Dim jsonValue As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc)`

Comment: Hackerman how do I get values/properties from jsonValue in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialze/parse your JSON string into Newtonsoft's `JObject`. Then you can access the properties like `Dictionary(Of String, String)`, for example :

```
Dim arg_strXml = "<Person><Name>foo</Name></Person>"
Dim doc = New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(arg_strXml)
Dim jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)
Dim jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonValue)
Console.WriteLine(jsonObject("Person")("Name"))
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kGDMf8)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
foo
```